# Streamlit .streamlit/config.toml

Tags: streamlit

I was trying to customize the theme of my streamlit app

I tried the available method. creating a config.toml file inside a .streamlit folder in the directory of my streamlit_app but when i run the app the custome theme is not showing.

Comment: Make sure `.streamlit/` is in the root directory of your project.

Answer (score 1):

I renamed my app to streamlit_app.py and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that your path is not set correctly; resulting in your application looking for a directory which doesnt exist.

If you add the following code to your app you will see the file path python is using as the current working directory.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path 
>>> Path.cwd()
PosixPath('/Users/myuser/projects/current-working-directory')
```

If the above outputs something which isn't your working directory then you will need to set it correctly.

In the case of streamlit this could be as simple as running your `streamlit`
command from the parent directory of the `.streamlit` directory.

---

You can also check paths and configuration using the `streamlit config show` command.

In the terminal run the command

```
streamlit config show
```

This will show you the configuration as aggregated by streamlit. It will also tell you where each config item is coming from for example.

```
...
[theme]

# The preset Streamlit theme that your custom theme inherits from.
# One of "light" or "dark".
# The value below was set in /Users/myuser/projects/current-working-directory/.streamlit/config.toml
base = "light"

# Primary accent color for interactive elements.
# The value below was set in /Users/myuser/projects/current-working-directory/.streamlit/config.toml
primaryColor = "#ff774b"

# Background color for the main content area.
# backgroundColor =
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try to list your .streamlit folder from your terminal or commandline like ls "$(pwd)"/.streamlit, to see if your are in your root directory of your project and if the .streamlit folders is there